# How can I store different graphs to show them at the end of the code?

Tags: python, graph

Okay so I'm making a code for simulating projectile motion in python, ideal case, we need to graph the difference between the velocity when the projectile is launched at 9 different angles. So I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid making 9 different arrays to store the results for graphing, like it would be nice if i could make the calculation and print the graph, store it, and use the same array for the next angle value.
ill leave my lil code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

print('Movimiento de un Proyectil')
v = eval(input('Ingrese el valor de la velocidad inicial '))  #pedimos valor inicial
dt = eval(input('Ingrese el salto que desee '))

g = 9.81
pasos = 200
angulos = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,85]
n = 9

x = []
y = []
ti = []
vx = []
vy = []
t = 0

a1= math.radians(10)
vi = v*(math.cos(a1))
vj = v*(math.sin(a1))

for i in range(pasos):
    vx.append(vi)
    vy.append(vj)
    ti.append(t)

    t = t + dt
    vi = vi
    vj = vj-(g*dt)

    if vj < 0:
        break

plot1 = plt.figure(1) #va a graficar la 1ra grafica
plt.plot(ti,vy,label="Velocidad sin resistencia del aire a 10 grados")
plt.xlabel("Tiempo [s]")
plt.ylabel("Vel [m/s]")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Comment: plot the graphs using `plt.plot()` for each iteration and call `plt.show()` whenever you want to show the plot.

Comment: Place a loop around your calculation `for angulo in angulos: ` collect your calculated arrays in a list, then plot all of them against the common x-axis in one go. And [`eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/8881141).